# My application already has user demographics information such gender age can I sync it to google analytics

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api, firebase-analytics, google-analytics-firebase, google-analytics-sdk

Google Analytics does not collect demographics(age, gender) information for all the users correctly. And as this age, gender, etc are reserved properties so I can not normally sync it to GA either. But my application already has such information about the user so somehow is there any way to sync that google analytics?

Comment: Did you consider putting your own values in custom user properties?

Comment: No, I wanted to leverage the existing predefined properties first to have consistency in the GA reports. However, if it is not possible then I would go with the custom properties with different keys for gender and age.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the information to Google Analytics as a custom dimension (user-level scope) based on the userId (also to be passed as a user-level custom dimension).

If your doubt is that it is personal 'confidential' information (PII), you can hash the data to make it non-speaking.